# deployed node.js app does not show up on default IP address while nginx default page works fine

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, heroku, centos7

I am deploying my node.js app to commercial VPS for the very first time. I have deployed the app through Heroku before but the whole process is so much different from that experience this time. I have read through and tried some VPS deployment articles that I got from Google but most of them are already outdated or the provided condition is not exactly the same. Somehow I've got both my nodejs app and nginx downloaded and running on my VPS but still I can't see the app's default page, whereas nginx default page is accessible from VPS default IP address.

My setup:

- OS:CentOS7
- VPS:Vultr
- Node.js(updated to 8.9.4 from server side as well)
- Express/Nginx(both installed and updated to latest stable)
- The app is already tested on both local PC and heroku, works fine.

I can see my app running from both console and pm2 monitor status and they are all green. However, I can't see the app running from the IP address and port.

my port setup from Node.js app

```
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("server is up at " + this.address().port)
})
```

I've used same port setup that I've used for Heroku(because Heroku doesn't support arbitrary port setting). It seems the app is running on port 3000.

`[root@myserver]ip a` result:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet ***.***.***.***/*** brd XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 78778sec preferred_lft 78778sec
    inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX/XX scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I've used the IP address that I masked with `***.***.***.***` above(both with and w/o port 3000), it shows the nginx default page but nodejs app doesn't show up. I've tried to modify my nginx.conf but suggestions are vary from pages to page, I couldn't figure out how to. Some say I should add `http://localhost:PORT;` as proxy pass inside locations bracket, while some others say I should add `http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:PORT;`. and even the location of `nginx.conf` that I should edit is also different from article to article. I've found some `nginx.conf` from the directories that are different from the suggestion but they don't even have `locations {}`bracket. I don't know which one to pick and it's hard to revert the decision since it easily gets mangled up.

Comment: If you are accessing http://some-ip:3000 and you're getting an nginx page, it's definitely wrong because only 1 server can run on a port. This would mean that you have both nginx and your node.js trying to use the same port (3000)

Comment: I've accessed [default IP address] without port number, it shows nginx default page. However, if I try to access the app with port number(3000), the server does not respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted default .html file specifications from `default.conf` in `/var/nginx/conf.d/` and filled in `localhost:[my app's listening port]`. It finally shows my Node.js app yay! The point is the `conf` file with `location` part is only one out there and not to forget delete default html setting when deploying apps other than pure html. It seems nginx automatically detects the app listening the request if there's no other default stuff.